# OpneCV-Python: How to draw multiple rectangles in multi-thread?

Tags: python, opencv

I used a `draw` function to draw a rectangle in the image.

```
def draw(image, location):
    ...
    cv2.rectangle(image, ...)
    return image
```

Since there are many `locations` of rectangles, I used the `map` function to draw those rectangles.

```
list(map(lambda x: draw(image, x), locations))
```

However, this function is executed serially. This means that the speed is very slow. Is there a way to draw rectangles on the same image in parallel?